# Sendgrid on FB Cloud functions, random requests fail with timeout error

Tags: node.js, firebase, function, timeout, sendgrid

This issue has been happening for a few weeks, some of our emails are not going out, and the SendGrid SDK (@sendgrid/mail for NodeJs) errors out with `timeout`, we have bumped the timeout time to 20000ms, but we still have some failures.

The way our scheduler system works we save a document in a document DB that holds the metadata for the email and that holds the ID of a GCP task, the GCP task calls happen 100%, and depending on the result it marks the document in the DB as "complete" or "failed", so we notice that those tasks that should be sending an email are marked as failed, and checking our Sentry logs those always have a "timeout" error.

The intriguing part is that some of those errored tasks did actually send an email, so we need to be safe on how to retry those on failure to avoid cases where we send the same email multiple times.

A few key points:

- If we don't set a "timeout" value in the Sendgrid config, it won't error out, so the task will be marked as complete even if no email goes out.
- Over 95% of our email tasks go out correctly, we were not able to link it to a time of the day or type of the email payload or specific email address, everything looks random, but I am sure there is a reason for those failures
- Could it be related to it running in a cloud function? The stack runs on Firebase cloud functions, we have a few debug logs to help it and all the logs show up correctly and the function finalizes the execution correctly

Example of our sender method:

```js
async function sendMail(templateName, msg, worker = {}) {
  try {
    const API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
    sgMail.setApiKey(API_KEY);
    // https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/main/docs/use-cases
    sgMail.setTimeout(20000);

    const env = getEnvironment();
    if (env === "development") {
      msg.to = "our-test-email@gmail.com";
    }
    msg.templateId = functions.config().sendgrid[templateName];
    const response = await sgMail.send(msg);
    console.log(`DEBUG: ${msg.to} Sendgrid response:`, response);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.body) {
      console.error(error.response.body);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
    Sentry.withScope(function (scope) {
      !isEmpty(worker) &&
        scope.setUser({
          firstName: user.firstName,
          lastName: user.lastName,
        });
      Sentry.captureException(error);
    });
    // Throw back the error to the caller to mark the task as failed
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "internal",
      msg.to ? `Error sending email to ${msg.to}` : "Error sending email",
      error
    ); 
  }
}
```

One example of the error:

```js
Error: timeout of 20000ms exceeded
  File "/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@sendgrid/client/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js", line 16, col 15, in createError
    var error = new Error(message);
  File "/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@sendgrid/client/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js", line 303, col 16, in RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout
    reject(createError(
  File "node:events", line 527, col 28, in RedirectableRequest.emit
  File "node:domain", line 537, col 15, in RedirectableRequest.emit
  File "/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js", line 164, col 12, in Timeout.<anonymous>
    self.emit("timeout");
  File "node:internal/timers", line 559, col 17, in listOnTimeout
  File "node:internal/timers", line 502, col 7, in processTimers
```

Extra response metadata:

````
scheduler/sender -> sendCompanyEmail() Company: FgTgemCNhhAscqTTMTWa Message: EMAIL HttpsError: Error sending email to ops-dev@trabapro.com
    at sendMail (/workspace/lib/src/helpers/index.js:67:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /workspace/lib/src/scheduler/sender.js:306:17
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async sendCompanyEmail (/workspace/lib/src/scheduler/sender.js:303:13) {
  code: 'internal',
  details: Error: timeout of 20000ms exceeded
      at createError (/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@sendgrid/client/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
      at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout (/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@sendgrid/client/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:303:16)
      at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:domain:537:15)
      at Timeout.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:164:12)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
    config: {
      url: '/v3/mail/send',
      method: 'post',
      data: ... 

            ...
      baseURL: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/',
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 20000,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: Infinity,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      transitional: [Object]
    },
    code: 'ECONNABORTED',
    request: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 1557,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [Array],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [ClientRequest],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send',
      _timeout: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    response: undefined,
    isAxiosError: true,
    toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
  },
  httpErrorCode: { canonicalName: 'INTERNAL', status: 500 }
```
````

Comment: I've not seen this before, especially not slow timeouts with the SendGrid API. With the scheduler, do you attempt to run many requests in parallel? It might be best to contact [SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us) to see if there might be a reason for the timeouts.

Comment: Hey @philnash, we are not technically running many requests in parallel, but the same cloud function is called multiple times after starting from a cold start as we have multiple tasks that send emails/messages going out at around the same time. 

We do have the same flow for push notifications without the timeouts, it's intriguing how the email call hangs there until it times out, my guess is that even if we bump it to 30s it would still timeout.

Comment: What I’m wondering is if you are starting a bunch of requests to SendGrid all at the same time, such that most complete successfully, but due to [the limits](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/how-to-use-the-sendgrid-v3-api/rate-limits) are being held back and then not completing. Though that would respond with a 429, which isn’t a timeout. Are you able to log the response headers along with the rest of the failing request to see what the `X-RateLimit` headers say?

Comment: @philnash yep added the extra metadata in response to the main post

Comment: Hmm, that metadata doesn't have a `response` because it was aborted after the timeout. I think, again, that this is something you might have to take to support. Your code is correct and the request should take less than 20 seconds, we probably can't solve it here.

Comment: @philnash do you think the SDK is expecting some sort of "close" after each execution? I wonder if the cloud function execution is sending multiple emails, with different payloads and different targets, using the same method, and perhaps all `sendMail` calls are being considered the same execution thus the timeout, but even if that was the case today we had one error and we only sent two emails at that moment, while we sent a dozen emails a few hours before just fine.

Comment: I genuinely don’t know at this point, sorry.